# При использовании time.sleep программа закрывается

Tags: python-3.x

Всем привет!
С вами снова рубрика "Тупые вопросы"!
Я хочу написать таймер включениЯ ПК.
Но при использовании функции sleep(модуля time) вроде программа ждет, но после сворачивания cmd программа и вовсе перестает работать.
В чем проблема? И есть ли другие способы поставить прошу на таймер? 
PS Скачивание аналогичной программы с Инета не предлагать, пользоваться встроенной тоже.

Мой код:

```
import os
import time
print("Эта программа выключит комп в заданное время\n")
input("Нажми enter...\n")
print("Есть три варианта\n1.Через N секунд\n2.Через N минут\n3.Через N часов\n")

times = [None, 'секунды', 'минуты','часы']
try:
    a = int(input())
    print("Хорошо ты выбрал", times[a],"\nА теперь через сколько должен выключиться комп?")
    a2 = int(input())
    print("Хорошо комп выключится через", str(a2), times[a][0]+".")
    if a == 1:
        time.sleep(a2)
        os.system('shutdown /p /f')
    elif a == 2:
        a2 *= 60
        time.sleep(a2)
        os.system('shutdown /p /f')
    elif a == 3:
        a2 *= 3600
        time.sleep(a2)
        os.system('shutdown /p /f')
except IndexError:
    print("Не понял o_O\nНе не не только от 1 до 3")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Ваш код, пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос

Comment: У меня всё прекрасно работает (за исключением подключения первого модуля, он там не нужен). Опишите подробнее, в какой ситуации не работает этот код.

Comment: Ну после отсчета(3,2,1) я скрываю cmd и процесс попросту закрывается

Comment: Первый модуль нужен для того чтобы можно было вообще скрыть командную строку(то есть не просто свернуть) как мне объяснили, но я пока убрал эту функцию

Comment: Скрываете как обычно? просто сворачиваете окно?

Comment: Да стандартным способом

Comment: Странно, я сделал всё в точности, как Вы описывали. Windows завершила работу, как и ожидалось.

Comment: Вы попробуйте поставить таймер минут на 15 и скрыть программу (возможно я как то не правильно выражаясь скрыть нажатием на вот такую хрен"-")

Comment: Я ставил на 10 секунд и да, скрывал нажатием именно на неё.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97488/discussion-between-v-mor-and-artur).